# What are the phonemes for this sounds?

Tags: hispanoamérica, fonología

I'm interested in what are the phones for the sounds **g**, **c**, **z** and **s** in Latino American Spanish as in **g**itano, tren**c**ito, **z**orro and ca**s**a, respectively. There are a few sites that have online conversion to phonetic transcription, but I couldn't find one that generates the transcription specifically for Latino American Spanish.

Comment: I do not think you mean phonemes? Perhaps phones?

Comment: @mdewey I see what you mean, the first sound in gitano could be [x] or [h], but the word has the same meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phonemes are /x, s, s, s/ in that order. The allophonic realization of /x/ in many Latino accents, however, is [h].